# APK(s) generated successfully for module 'tk_app.app' with 0 build variants android dolphin

Tags: android, android-studio, android-version, release-apk

After updating android studio from arctic fox to dolphin it return the message **Generate Signed APK: APK(s) generated successfully for module 'test_app.app' with 0 build variants** but I'm not able to find the exact file path for apk.

> It is not where I declared the path neither in the
> **app\build\outputs\apk\debug** It was working in **Android Arctic Fox**, It seem that there is something wrong with new version.
> Also the issue is only with **signed APK** .**AAB**  is working fine in my case.

This is my gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.entitcs.office_attendance"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 63
        versionName "2.48"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }

    productFlavors {}
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: this is some bug in recent Android Studio version, the apk does get generated and you can manually check in the Folder with your flavor name in the build directly, the file will be present there

Comment: @AnkitWala APK was generating while i create the **signed aab** file in the assigned path.

Comment: This helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/72562297/988941